# How to get machine's browser to resolve to domain assigned to self?

Tags: apache-2.2, connection, loopback

I have a machine running Apache HTTP server which works fine hosting the website for all machines except itself.  When trying to load itself, I get the following error in Firefox:

```
The connection has timed out
The server at www.someDomain.com is taking too long to respond.
```

It also fails when I use the ip address that the domain resolves too.  Using localhost works fine.

What is going wrong that loop back to self does not working beyond localhost?  How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer is blocking that IP somewhere. Check the firewall rules. Your machine is probably allowing traffic on the loopback adapter correctly (127.0.0.1 aka localhost) but isn't allowing the traffic to loopback to the local IP. You might also have something in the routing table completely mucked up. (In either case this would be a strange configuration, but entirely possible)